# Multiples Forms rendering a card

Tags: reactjs, forms, components

I'm having a lot of troubles trying to render the data I passed into my inputs to render a "contact" card.

I'm handling the inputs, changing the states accordingly, but when it comes to the final state, rendering a "Contact card" with all my data I just don't know how to make it works.

I think the problem is at my "renderCard" method.
If someone could give me a hand I think i'm really close but yet so far..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Todo extends Component {

  state = {
    nom: '',
    age: '',
    ville: '',
    items: [],
    start: 0
  };


  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      nom: '',
      age: '',
      ville: '',
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.nom, this.state.age, this.state.ville],
      start: 1
    });

  }


  renderCard = () => {
    return this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
                {item.nom}
                {item.age} 
                {item.ville} 
            </div>    
        );
    });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card mb-3">
          <div className="card-header">Ajouter une Personne</div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Nom</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  name="nom"
                  value={this.state.nom}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Age</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  name="age"
                  value={this.state.age}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Ville</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  name="ville"
                  value={this.state.ville}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>


              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Créez votre Fiche !</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>


        {this.renderCard()}


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making mistake in setting the items in state on submit. I hope the items should be a array of objects 
Please check the below code

onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      nom: '',
      age: '',
      ville: '',
      items: [...this.state.items, {nom:this.state.nom, age:this.state.age, ville: this.state.ville}],
      start: 1
    });

Comment: Wow... i've spend 2 days on that one and never thought it was the problem !
Thanks a lot and have a nice day / night !